it showing error while creating react app
PS C:\Users\ishil\OneDrive\Desktop\JSapps> npx create-react-app my-app
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall lstat
npm error path C:\Users\ishil\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\ishil\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ishil\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-08-26T17_03_20_844Z-debug-0.log

